# What's difference between "long" and "long int" and "long long" vs "long long int"

Tags: c++

While coding I realised that there is no difference in these terms. Please clarify them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference between `long` and `long int`, and between `long long` and `long long int`.  `long` is a size modifier for `int` and `double`.  If an actual type is not explicitly stated, `int` is assumed.